# How do I decide which IPv4 address to use?

Tags: c#, ip-address

In an environment with multiple IPv4 addresses, how do I choose which one to listen on? I've had mixed luck with the following code:

```
foreach(IPAddress addr in Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()))
    if (addr.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
        if (!IPAddress.IsLoopback(addr))
            return addr.ToString();
```

Since it does not consider the following interface adapter to be a loopback address:

```
Ethernet adapter loopback:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Loopback Adapter
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : XX.XX.XX.XX.XX.XX
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.XXX.XXX(Preferred) 
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : XXX: XXX: XXX:XXXX::XXX
                                    XXX: XXX: XXX:XXXX::XXX
                                    XXX: XXX: XXX:XXXX::XXX
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

I've seen some programmers assume a `NetworkInterface` named "Local Area Connection" exists and is always the correct interface, but I don't think that's the right approach.

Comment: Why don't you listen on *all* interfaces? That's what most server applications do unless they are configured to do otherwise.

Comment: Heinzi++ :) Use `IPAddress.Any` as the IP address in that case.

Comment: If in doubt, listen on all interfaces. If you want only a certain IP address, the user should select it (like it's done in Wireshark). Otherwise the software cannot know what's intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no sense filtering interfaces as you may have multiple cards on a device (ethernet & wifi for instance). If you're developping a server component you will certainly want to get all the requests whatever interface they use.